# DRF serializer.save () object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I try to save extended data to my object in ModelsetView

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(from_user=self.request.user)
```

I get error:
'User' object is not iterable

DRF version 3.1.3 
What am I doing wrong?

```
class MailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Mail
    queryset = Mail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateMailSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateMailSerializer
        return MailSerializer


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(from_user=self.request.user)


class Mail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_users')
    to_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='to_users')



class CreateMailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    to_users = EmailRelationField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Mail
```

Comment: Add code for serializers and models also

Comment: Can you include the traceback as well? I suspect there might be something else hidden away here that isn't obvious at first.

Comment: Are you sure you maybe have some unfinished migrations? Just to make sure.